# DB2 SQL Insert NULL into NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT

Tags: sql, db2, default-value, notnull

I faced a problem when inserting a NULL value into a column defined as NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT values.
In this example, I removed most of the columns for illustration purposes.

```
CREATE TABLE
    FKTIM04
    (
        OBJECTID CHARACTER(32) NOT NULL,
        UP_CHANGE_CL CHARACTER(1) DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL,
        UP_CTRL_CL CHARACTER(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_FKTIM04 PRIMARY KEY (OBJECTID)
    );
```

When I execute this SQL statement, there is an error:

```
INSERT INTO KTI.FKTIM04 (
    UP_Change_CL
    ,UP_ctrl_CL
    ,ObjectID
    )
VALUES (
    NULL
    ,NULL
    ,'UMSTM0LW8A8Z50DT4WA7U93EEQDRXRTH'
    )
```

Error:

> [Code: -407, SQL State: 23502]  Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT
>   NULL column "TBSPACEID=2, TABLEID=1298, COLNO=46" is not allowed..
>   SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, DRIVER=4.22.29

I know that the column is defined as NOT NULL. If it tries to insert a NULL into the column, shouldn't it take the DEFAULT value instead?

Please teach me how to get the DEFAULT values to be inserted instead.
What should I look out for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The default value will be used for a column if a value is not supplied in the `INSERT` statement for this column.
 
So don't include the columns that you want to get their default values in the list like this:

```
INSERT INTO KTI.FKTIM04 (
    ObjectID
    )
VALUES (
   'UMSTM0LW8A8Z50DT4WA7U93EEQDRXRTH'
    )
```

this way the row will be inserted and the 2 columns, since they were not specified in the list, will get their default values.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=715d6ebf18fac450e62b886c138f9e0f).
Another way to achieve the same is by using DEFAULT keyword:

```
INSERT INTO FKTIM04 (
    UP_Change_CL
    ,UP_ctrl_CL
    ,ObjectID
    )
VALUES (
    DEFAULT
    ,DEFAULT
    ,'UMSTM0LW8A8Z50DT4WA7U93EEQDRXRTH'
    )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=30aaa0d78591e902e5b38d91cdfcc38f).